# Simplest way to get inputs from text/xls file for update/delete SQL statement without using temp table/external table concepts

Tags: sql, plsql, sqlplus

```
update department 
set department_name = 'test.txt' 
where department_id ='test.txt'
```

In other words: I simply need to get inputs for update statement from file (text file/xls) without using external table or temp table concepts in database.

Comment: An excerpt from the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) _Don't ask about ... Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)_

Comment: Perhaps Oracle's PL/SQL package [UTL_FILE](http://psoug.org/definition/UTL_FILE.htm) is relevant?